# In what layer of a project do common extension methods belong?

Tags: c#, architecture

I'm curious what "layer" of a system common extensions that are global to the application belong in.  For instance, I may have extensions that let me use the Rails-like "DaysAgo", "MonthsAgo", etc. type of extension method  on integers.  What layer of a project does this typically belong in?  I was thinking Infrastructure, but that seems to mean database-related (e.g. base repositories and data access).  I have a "Core" library project, so maybe it belongs there?

I understand that you want to group extensions that are related to a specific group of classes, but these are essentially used across the entire application.  In the days before extension methods, they would be in a `Utilities` static class or the like, so where should they live now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can (better) create multiple infrastructure projects based on scope for example:

Infrastructure.Common (here comes the general infrastructure - best fit for extension methods)
Infrastructure.Data (Data access)
Infrastrcuture. bla bla bla

Answer (score 3):

I would put these methods at the lowest possible layer where those objects/entities exist.

either in the interfaces, or in the entities or in a core assembly, the lowest the better so all upper layers can use it :)

Answer (score 2):

I would put them in a base project (something like 'Core') that is referenced from all other projects. If you start a new project in some time you can reuse these extension methods easily.

I would think about the namespaces you will use for your different sets of extension methods. If some really belong to Data, just put them in a Core.Data namespace so your code in other projects won't be cluttered with extension methods that have no meaning in that context.

Answer (score 0):

Consider putting logic that is outside the scope of the entire application in its own assembly or assemblies.